# How do I place the point of a leaflet marker on given lat/lon coordinates?

Tags: css, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a leaflet map with lots of basic markers (about 1000 in germany, to be precise). The map is at

http://geotools.gurkensalat.com/osm-mosques/map

I will add a better link when I get permalinks to work, until then, the node which I am asking about is the one slightly to the east and north of the red marker.

When I create a marker for coordinates lat="48.1364" lon="11.3872928" and put it on the map, the marker is shown slightly to the left and bottom. The coordinates are exactly those of the OSM node itself. Any ideas how I can move the marker so the tip of the marker is exactly *on* the node, or at least pretty close to it?

[image: screenshot from my map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to tell without a live example, but my best bet would be that you have some CSS on your page that is interfering with the map and shifting your tiles up and to the right, or your markers down and to the left.

---

Nope, that's not it - you're truncating the numbers.

Desired:

```
[48.1364, 11.3872928, "OSM / Germering / Germering Camii"],
```

On this page:

```
[48.136, 11.387, "OSM / Germering / Germering Camii"],
```

So, the thing causing the problem is your source data, not Leaflet.

Comment: Indeed, it was a rounding problem, in this case with using [ExtendedMessageFormat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/ExtendedMessageFormat.html) which gave me only three significant digits in the output.